# How to return text from an element into variable in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

Here's the deal - **getText()** method returns promise, it's okay in case when you are using it inside of **expect()**, but when I'm trying to return `string` value of an element into variable, it returns promise. Here is the code:

```
var text = mainPage.counter().getText().then((text) => {
        return text;
})
```

Is there any way to get the text and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise’s value could be resolved only by another promise, you should probably check this post : [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

so in your case -

```
 var data = mainPage.counter().getText().then((text) => {
    return text;
   });
 // at this point data is still a managed promise!
 data.then((text) => {
   console.log(text); // your text would be printed!
  });
```

Comment: Code duplicate for promises handling. better follow: var data = mainPage.counter().getText();
data.then((text) => {
   console.log(text); // your text would be printed!
  });

Comment: yes this could also be done, just wanted to stick to the qn though!

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable 'string' at global level and store text value to it inside then(function(){})

```
Code snippet:
   var string; 
   mainPage.counter().getText().then((text) => {
      string=text;
    });
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this variable should be declared only at global scope?

Comment: This won't work, string will be `undefined` in this case! you can check it out.

Comment: @ByteSurfer the code you wrote should work. but you said, its not working. So i suggested to declare a global variable and store that text for furture uasage of it

Answer (score 0):

*Let the variable be a promise*, resolve when needed:

```
var text = mainPage.counter().getText();
// some other code

text.then(function (realTextValue) {
    console.log(realTextValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use await and make your it block async.

```
// I'm using const x = await this.getElementText();

    public async getElementText(elem) {
         return elem.getText().then((text) => {
              return text;
          })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I had a similar problem trying to get the text from an element and resolved it like this:

```js
var yourVar = '';
element.getText()
     .then(function(text){
         yourVar = text;
         return yourVar;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

`var text = function(){
return mainPage.counter().getText();
};`